# CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in

Tags: git, github, conflict, git-push, git-pull

I'm trying to push a project using git but i always get these conflicts.

```
Auto-merging App.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/user.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in App.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/user.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist
Auto-merging .gitignore
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in .gitignore
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I added the `App.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/user.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist`
to `.gitignore` and after that i started to get a conflict on that file.

What can i do, besides `git-pull` which deletes the majority of files in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this :

```
git pull --rebase https://github.com/yours master/name of your branch
```

and after some working around i solved the problem.

Comment: Not sure if i should just delete this question

Answer (score 0):

Simply edit the `.gitignore` file, resolving the conflicts, and then add it to the index, and commit.

Comment: Well, that was what i did. I explained that in the answer